# custom criteria in excel validation , using OR statement

Tags: excel-formula

I would like to use Excel validation to allow only entries which are either a date from this calendar year or next or text from a predefined list.

For example today is 12th Jan 2017.
If a date is entered (in say cell C1) then this date must be in 2017 or 2018.
If text is entered then it must match one of the entries in a predefined list.
Let's say the list in this example is named 'reasons' (these reasons would be something like 'To be confirmed' , 'beyond planning horizon' etc.)

01/12/2019 should be rejected
01/12/2018 should be accepted
'beyond this month' should be rejected
'beyond planning horizon' should be accepted

I believe I should be using custom validation but I would appreciate if anyone could help with the syntax, please.

Comment: Welcome to SO, I done something similar about a year ago. I'll try dig out the old workbook and look at what I done.

Comment: Thanks Glitch_Doctor

Comment: So, I can't find the sheet in question. Are you hoping for a list drop-down because I won't be able to provide that, just playing with custom validation to see if I can replicate what I did.

Comment: i don't need a drop-down, thanks;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, we finally made it (for some reason the validation formula did not like my `COUNTIF()` being part of the `OR()` statement so I had to nest a `TRUE` result as part of a separate `IF()` statement:

`=IF(COUNTIF(reasons,C1)=1,TRUE,OR(YEAR(C1)=YEAR(TODAY()),YEAR(C1)=YEAR(TODAY())+1))`

Like you said this will be in custom validation. Be sure that the `$$`'s dont go in it as it will need to update the cell range down the column.

The logic is if the entry appears in the named range reasons *once* then TRUE otherwise do the OR year matching this year or next (returns TRUE by default if the conditions are correct).

Comment: Just tried this and it worked exactly as I wanted. Very much appreciate your help.

Comment: Glad that it worked, thank you for accepting the answer!